# Как узнать размер веб сайта перед закачкой?

Tags: wget

Я скачиваю сайт www.catb.org/ Эрика Рэймонда с помощью программы HTTrack Website Copier и скачал 230 мб. У меня плохой скорость интернета и не хочу мучаться сколько весит сайт и сколько времени нужно для скачивание сайта и мой вопрос: Как узнать размер полного сайта (с внутренними ссылками и материалами без внешных ссылках и материалах) перед скачиванием сайта?

Comment: Никак. Не факт, что даже сам владелец сайта в курсе

Comment: А как же программы менеджера закачек перед скачивание программы и другие материалы в интернете определяют его размер? Владелец сайта же ставляет сайт в сервер со всеми файлами и каталогами с определённом размере может есть способ узнать этого !

Comment: Узнать размер **одного файла** — можно, именно размеры отдельных файлов менеджеры закачек и показывают. Узнать размер **всего веб-сайта** — нельзя, ни в одном менеджере закачек вы такую функцию не найдёте (кроме торрентов, но вопрос не о них). Если на сервере работают скрипты, генерирующие контент, то размер сайта становится абсолютно непредсказуемым, и владелец сайта никак не сможет узнать его размер. Данные, которые вы скачаете, могут оказаться размером в два-три раза больше, чем то, что хранится на сервере на самом деле — всё из-за серверных скриптов.

Comment: Он, теоретически, может быть бесконечным или неопределённым. Так что никак нельзя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы пользуетесь `wget`, а в метке вы указали его, то у него есть ключ `--spider`, позволяющий вытащить метаданные, но для рекурсивного прохода по всем ссылкам нужно уже писать скрипт.

Comment: извините за метку "wget" ничего другого я не нашёл и у меня нет достаточного количество репутации чтобы сделать свои метки. Я использую программу HTTrack Website Copier и там я не нашёл способ как узнать размер сайта перед скачиванием и хотелось бы узнать есть ли какой нибудь другая программа или что нибудь ещё чтоб узнать такую информацию?